# Plotting intraday only n days back

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=4
study("PlayGround", overlay=true)

history_days = input(4, "History days")

source = close*0.95
plot(source)
```

This yields
*(yellow highlight added manually)*

[image]

I'm attempting to show the history of a series that has a user-configurable length.

In the example given, the history length is set to 4 days.
So the plot should start at april 29th.
Which means only the yellow highlight should be plotted.
However, I don't know how to implement that.
*The `history_days` variable is not used in the script, because I don't know how yet*

The pine script [execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html) is such that it executes the script at each bar.
This means that we won't know the date of the last bar until it is reached.
Also, in order to calculate the date on which the plot should start, we have to take into account weekends and trading holidays.
In the example above, the last bar is on May 4th (a monday), and 4 trading days back is April 29th (wednesday).
But there are 6 calendar days between those dates, because it spans over a weekend.

Any tips on how to tackle this problem are welcomed.

Comment: I think this is what [max_bars_back](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_max_bars_back) in the Study Properties is for.

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=4
study("Days before", "", true)
daysBack = input(4)

_MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
lastBarDate = timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), hour(timenow), minute(timenow), second(timenow))
thisBarDate = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute, second)
daysLeft = floor((lastBarDate - thisBarDate) / _MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY)
inRange = daysLeft <= daysBack

ma = sma(close, 30)
plot(ma, "ma", inRange ? color.orange : na)
plotchar(daysLeft, "daysLeft", "", location.top)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the useful suggestion. When I use the example from your link, and modify it to also include days back, and set it to 4 days back, it only plots a line on the last 2 trading days, because it includes a weekend. Is there a way to compensate for non-trading days?

Comment: Based on the link you provided, I worked around the problem by having the user input a day/month/year from which I calculate a timestamp(). All bars after that timestamp can plot the history series.

Comment: I think that's the best way to go. Updated answer with a variation of a technique you can use to detect the number of days left before the end of the chart, but it doesn't solve the holiday/weekend problem either, and produces different results on conventional and 24/7 markets, so not ideal.